# Issue with the implementation of the simplesamlphp library into my web application

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, identity

I tried to implement the simplesamlphp library into my web application. But when I call the *requireAuth()* function I get a PHP fatal error message. Uncaught Exception: Loader: Illegal character in filename.....
It seems like he can't resolve the Class **SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Auth\Source\SP**
But I don't know why.
Does anyone have a idea how to fix this?
I already deleted the whole simplesamlphp installation and reinstalled it.

I use the following code:

```
require 'var/www/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php';
$lAuthSrc = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');
if (!$lAuthSrc->isAuthenticated()) {
  $lAuthSrc->requireAuth();
}
$lAttributes = $lAuthSrc -> getAttributes();
foreach($lAttributes as $lAttribute) {
  print_r($lAttribute);
}
```

Some additional informations:
The configured authentication source test works fine. If I login via the configured authentication source, everything works fine and I don't get any error messages (the requireAuth() function don't get called in this case).
I use the latest version of simplesamlphp v.1.18.3

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: $lAuthSrc = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('defaultsp');Try above code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but unfortunatly this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I discovered this morning the issue. The issue was the autoloader which I use for my own application. I registered the application autoloader in another file which gets executed before the code you see above. And simplesamlphp uses some conditions like:

```
if (!class_exists($className))
```

And beacuse I registered my application autoloader before the function class_exists checked if the class exists in my application. In my application I don't use namespaces and this was the issue.

To fix this issue, I unregistered my application autoloader before using the simplesamlphp code and registered the autoloader again after the simplesamlphp code.

I hope this will save some of you headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it looks like your path is messed up on the require... are you sure you should be using:

`require 'var/www/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php';`

and not

`require '/var/www/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php';`

Do you really have a 'var/www' subdirectory relative to the location of the script? That looks wrong to me. If you include that first `/` before `var` it makes that path absolute to the typical install location for SSP.